# How use streams for loop in jdk8?

Tags: java, loops, java-8, stream

How to use the for loop like this in jdk8.

```
for (ClassAttendanceParent classAttendanceParent : list) {
                TransportAttendanceFormBean tb = new TransportAttendanceFormBean();
                tb.setDate(classAttendanceParent.getAttendancedate().toString());
            }
```

in JDK8(How to convert the above for loop)

```
  list.forEach((ClassAttendanceParent element) -> System.out.println(element.getAttendancedate()));
```

Comment: Well, seems like you took a stab at it at least. Is there anything wrong with what you have?

Comment: I am not able to create the new object inside that for loop  TransportAttendanceFormBean tb = new TransportAttendanceFormBean();

Comment: Why not? Do you get an error?. If so, what is it? Can you show exactly what you tried?

Comment: what happens to `tb` in your original code ? It seems like it's getting garbage collected

Comment: same thing i need to convert into jdk8 for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    list.forEach(element->{
        TransportAttendanceFormBean tb = new TransportAttendanceFormBean();
        tb.setDate(element.getAttendancedate().toString());         
    });
```

Or(no need to create new object in each iteration)

```
  TransportAttendanceFormBean tb = new TransportAttendanceFormBean();
  list.forEach(element->{   
        tb.setDate(element.getAttendancedate().toString());         
    });
```